# Certbot Https - Nginx - Docker: Port Clash

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, digital-ocean, certbot

I'm running Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic in a DigitalOcean Droplet

I run the commands from https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-nginx as directed.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install certbot python3-certbot-nginx
```

And then the "1 step setup" command

```
sudo certbot --nginx
```

Everything works fine until I go to run

```
docker-compose up --build
```

and it returns

```
Creating nginx ... error

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nginx (69110ad70db81c0b563eac20f90a94358702588dcbd604d7672292d8f082d3862607): 
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use'       

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nginx (69011ad70db81c0b563eac20f90a94358702588dcbd604d7672292d8f082d3862607): 
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use'       
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

My .conf file looks as such (and obviously updates with the "sudo certbot --nginx" command)

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://website:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    } }
```

Docker-compose nginx service

```
  nginx: 
      restart: always
      build: ./nginx
      image: 'nginx:1.13'
      container_name: nginx
      volumes:
        - .:/domain
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
      networks: 
        - web_nw
      links: 
        - domain
      depends_on:
        - domain
```

What am I missing? It has to be something so simple but I cannot figure out how to get my Nginx container up and running with the newly assigned Https/SSL.

Has anyone ran into this before?

Comment: [here](https://sitegeist.de/blog/typo3-blog/docker-compose-setup-mit-nginx-reverse-proxy.html) is an example on using nginx as a reverse proxy and letsencrypt certificates. May be not the very same situation you are facing, but solves talking to letsencrypt via a `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` helper image. May be that could help. The article is in German however.

Comment: For your log. I got this error > `tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use'`  when trying to run a service and the port is taken by a different process.